# Is there any way to know if a download is happening

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, download

Is there any way to know if a download through a browser is happening? (I am thinking of creating an app,though whole concept relies whether this particular feature is possible or not)

For example: Say I start downloading a file from a web browser, and a program is running in the background( preferably written in Java) which can detect that a download is happening and it can get access to the link.

Ideally it should be able to detect from any browser, but even if it works with one browser it is fine for me at the moment! Any ideas if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to do the same thing. My first thoughts are :
 1. Low level browser independent :
Sniff traffic and filter captured packets (Protocols HTTP/FTP + other filter rules). You may use [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) or even try the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) approach.
 2. High level browser dependent : Create browser plug-ins ([BHO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object) for Microsoft Internet Explorer, [Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) for Google Chrome, [Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) for Mozilla Firefox)